# Efficiënt writing to a SQL Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I am new to programming in c# and have no experience with SQL at all. But I used to do some programming when VB6 came out. I am writing a program that creates a SQL Server database from a textfile which is a dump, generated by a computer. It has data in it for which I need to create +- 200 tables and then I read the file again to populate all the tables.

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2014 installed and Visual Studio Express 2015.

I am able to read the textfile and determine the tables I need, I can open the database and create a table. I have three questions, two of them I can sort of find the answer to on this forum and one question that still mystifies me.

The first question is if it is efficient to create a new connection every time to create a new table. The C# program "designs" the table which I put in the string "NewType" then the CreateBlockType is called to create the new table. After that a new table is created and send to CreateBlockType again. This will happen 200 times and later when filling the actual data itself maybe a couple of 45000 times.

```
static void CreateBlockType(string NewType)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=WIJ-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FoxData;Integrated Security=True;"))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(NewType, conn)) 
              command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

The two other questions are:

- How do I check if a table exists (did not find a good answer)
- And the last is a bit difficult to explain but lets say the file contains two Customer types of data, they have the same name but the columns might be slightly different, so I need to create two tables but what is a fast method to compare an existing table in the database with the new one the c# program just created. Or to put it more basic: does this table in this format exists, yes or no.

I am sorry for being long winded, bad habit of me :-(

Sincerely,
Rob.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider splitting your question into individual posts. Avoid questions that ask for people's opinions. Feel free to review SO help about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, if you have multiple questions, you should really break them up into multiple posts.

For question #1: .NET will transparently cache `SqlConnection`s, so there should be very little overhead associated with rapidly creating and closing connections, *so long as the connection string is always the same*.

For questions #2 and #3, you should look into the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS views respectively.

Comment: SQL Server has another way to check if objects exist: the function `OBJECT_ID`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167576/check-if-table-exists-in-sql-server)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244126/net-connection-pooling) gives some hints about creating connections and connection pooling.

Comment: All three parts of this question are already answered in other questions.

Comment: First of all, thanks for replying, I will look into the links you provided. One thing I knew was comming is, me asking something already beeing asked.

Comment: Problem is that its not easy to prhase a question so it is uniform to all others with the same question.